# Crashlytics download issue

Tags: crashlytics-beta

I have one question about Crashlytics Beta service. 
We are experiencing download problem. Download is very slow, sometimes even 1 hour for 200 MB app, but only from company network. When I download from mobile network it take a few minutes. 
Is there any download limitation per IP address? 
Can you suggest me, what could cause this bad download performance?

Thank you in advance 
Marko

Comment: Shouldn't you contact crashanalytics instead of writing here? How could we know the policies?